# recursively $x_n$ by the equation $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + x_n -3$ for $0≤n$,

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the succession of real numbers defined recursively $x_n$ by the equation $x_{n+1} = x_n^2 + x_n -3$ for $0≤n$, Determine the initial values  $x_0$​​for which you get a constant succession $x_n$.

I really stuck with this problem of sequences some help to solve this please!! ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $x_0^2=3$, then

$$x_{1} = x_0^2 + x_0 -3=x_0.$$

Answer (score 3):

If a solution is constant, then $x_n = x_{n+1} = x_{n+2} =  \ldots$ , so we can set $x_n = x_{n+1} = x$ in the recurrence relation obtaining:
$$ x = x^2 + x - 3$$
Hence $x^2 = 3 = x_0^2$, so $x_0 = \sqrt{3}$ or $x_0 = -\sqrt{3}$. Plugging both into the recurrence relation shows that they indeed lead to constant solutions.